# Unknown method "saveAll"

Tags: cakephp

I have just baked my first test project after few years and.. I'm confused.

```
public function add()
{
    $post = $this->Posts->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $post = $this->Posts->patchEntity($post, $this->request->getData());
        if ($this->Posts->saveAll($post)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The post has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The post could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
    $parentPosts = $this->Posts->ParentPosts->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('post', 'parentPosts'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['post']);
}
```

After I submit form I get

Unknown method "saveAll"

BadMethodCallException

All I have changed is

```
$this->Posts->save($post)
```

(which works fine) to

```
$this->Posts->saveAll($post)
```

Why this method is unknown here? It's the same like with saveAssociated and etc.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From CakePHP version 3.2.8 you can save multiple records at once, but the function to use is ***$this->Posts->saveMany($post)***. You can use the code mentioned on the cakephp documents.

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-multiple-entities